# Преобразование строк с двумя разделителями в список списков

Tags: python, строки

Как Преобразовать строку вида `"1,2 2,3 3,4"` в такой список (типа `int`): `[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [106]: res = [list(map(int, x.split(","))) for x in "1,2 2,3 3,4".split()]

In [107]: res
Out[107]: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```